# OOP how to get the script (a game) to run

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to get my head around OOP using Python. Working through a tutorial I've been instructed to make a game. Earlier in the tutorial I made a game just using functions but now I have to use classes and objects.

Once I have my objects though I'm unsure how the get things moving. Here's the gist of it:

```
class Scene(object):

    def enter(self):
        pass

class Scene1(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        print "Some text describing the scene bla bla"
        def someFunction that requires raw_input and a correct answer
        return 'Scene2'

class Scene2(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        print "Some text describing the scene bla bla"
        def someFunction that requires raw_input and a correct answer
        return 'Scene3'

class Scene3(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        print "Some text describing the scene bla bla"
        def someFunction that requires raw_input and a correct answer
        return 'finished'
```

There is more to the game than that, but I've just slimmed it right down to the part I'm having trouble with.

The tutorial author hints to use another object to run the game, an "engine" that would start with scene1 and run through each scene till 'finished' is returned. He does have an example but it was for a more complex game so I've tried to ignore it. I think he wants us to use a while loop though.

But `while what?` What logic could I use to run the game? I'm a learner as you may be able to tell. Do I have all of the objects that I need? What would be the best way to "run" the game?

Comment: Is this an online tutorial you could link?

Comment: This isn't really a good use of objects, as there's no data being encapsulated: you'd never have more than one instance of each class.

Comment: @DanielRoseman there could be multiple instances of the scenes depending on the players answers to the "someFunction", which could return the current scene again.

Comment: @FredLarson it's LPTHW ex45 but I wanted to avoid posting the link in the hopes of keeping the question very specific on how to run the scenes (there's more to the exercise than I have posted). It's what I cannot get my head around - how to run each scene in order, except when the player get's a wrong answer (the function that uses raw input, in which case the player dies or starts the scene again)

Comment: No, that's still not multiple instances. It's just calling the same one again. The reason to have a class would be if there was just one Scene class, and `description` was an instance attribute on that class.

Comment: Define a class `Game` to control things via a `while` (or some other) loop in one of its methods (like `run()` or `play()`) until some event occurs that means it finished -- i.e. a goal has been reached, all but one of the players have been eliminated, the enemy is dead, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Class that holds all scenes. The `run()` method loops through all scenes and execute the `enter()` method, which will output both: the `print` and the `return` string.

```
class Engine:
    def __init__(self):
        self.scenes = [Scene1(),Scene2(),Scene3()]
    def run(self):
        for s in self.scenes:
            print s.enter()

Engine().run()
```

Output:

```
Some text describing the scene bla bla
Scene2
Some text describing the scene bla bla
Scene3
Some text describing the scene bla bla
finished
```

**Update to comment**: do it more dynamically:

```
class Scene1(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        print "Some text describing the scene bla bla"
        raw = raw_input("Guess the number")
        if raw != "42":
            return 'Scene1'
        return 'Scene2'

class Engine:
    def __init__(self):
        self.scenes = {'Scene1':Scene1(),'Scene2':Scene2(),'Scene3':Scene3()}
    def run(self):
        next = 'Scene1'
        while True:
            if next == 'finished':
                break;
            next = self.scenes.get(next).enter()

Engine().run()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to run that and got:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex45.py", line 110, in <module>
    Engine().run()
  File "ex45.py", line 19, in run
    for s in scenes:
NameError: global name 'scenes' is not defined

Comment: Also, I should have been more explicit, but depending on a players answers to a scene puzzle (a function that requires raw input), the next scene is actually dynamic. If the player gets each question correct then yes, they will go from scene 1 - 3 but they can repeat scenes and even encounter the death scene for game over. It looks like using this method a player will go through scenes 1-3 regardless?

Comment: You miss the **self**.scenes keyword in the for-loop. Self means it's part of the actual class and not a global value. To do it more dynamically, instead of printing you can check the `return` value first and decide which scene is the next.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The syntax is what this beginner was most familiar with so I went with this one

Comment: Thanks again @andpei. Almost there I think except I now got:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex45.py", line 87, in <module>
    Engine().run()
  File "ex45.py", line 19, in run
    next = self.scenes.get(next).enter()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enter'

Answer (score 1):

the arguments about this being a good canidate for oop not withstanding

```
class Scene1:
   def enter(self):
      print "a scene"
      raw_input("Hit Enter To Go To Next Scene")
      return "Scene2"

class Scene2:
   def enter(self):
      print "a different scene"
      raw_input("Hit Enter To Go Back:")
      return "Scene1"

class Engine:
     def __init__(self,sceneDict,startKey=1):
        self._scenes = sceneDict
        self._current = self._scenes[startKey] 
     def run(self):
        while True:
            next_scene_key = self._current.enter()
            self._current = self._scenes[next_scene_key]

Engine({"Scene1":Scene1(),"Scene2":Scene2()},"Scene1").run()
```

is one example of many ways to accomplish this

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was more familiar with the methodology from an alternative answer and so went with what I was more comfortable with. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you see a lot of repeated code in an OOP-project, you most probably are working against OOP and not with it.

Don't make a new class for each scene, but one object (of scene) for each.

This is a very simple example of how to implement your "engine" (last 4 lines):

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

class Scene:
    def __init__(self, name, welcome, question, answer):
        self.name = name
        self.welcome = welcome
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer
        self.connected = []

    def connect(self, otherScene):
        self.connected.append(otherScene)

    def enter(self):
        print(self.welcome)
        while (input(self.question + ' ') != self.answer): pass #raw_input in py2
        if not self.connected: return
        print('\nWhither goest thou?')
        for i, scene in enumerate(self.connected):
            print('{}: {}'.format(i, scene.name))
        while True:
            try:
                i = int(input('? '))
                return self.connected[i]
            except ValueError:
                print('I understand thee not.')
            except IndexError:
                print('I understand thee not.')

#creating the scenes
house = Scene('A house',
    'Thou art standing in front of a house. The landlord talketh to thee.',
    'What is the top speed of an uncharged swallow?',
    '42')
bridge = Scene('A bridge',
    'Thou seest a bridge guarded by a knight clothèd in black.',
    'What is the capital of England?',
    'London')
swamp = Scene('A swamp',
    'Thou enterst a foul morast and a witch eyeballth thee.',
    'What is the capital of Azerbaijan?',
    'Baku')
castle = Scene('A castle',
    'The castle! A fair maiden greeteth thee.',
    'What is my name?',
    'Peach')

#connecting the scenes
house.connect(bridge)
house.connect(swamp)
bridge.connect(castle)
swamp.connect(castle)

#the game engine
nextScene = house
while nextScene:
    nextScene = nextScene.enter()
print('Fin')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The methodology was beyond my narrow realm of familiarity in OOP so far but thanks all the same.

Comment: @DougFirr Just to give you some ideas for future projects.